# How to read big file in php without being memory limit

Tags: php, file, memory-limit

I'm trying to read a file line by line. The problem is the file was too big(over 500000 line) and I reach out the memory limit. I wonder how to read the file without being memory limit.

I'm thinking about the solution multi threads(like split the file into smaller group(100000 line per group) and read it in multi threads), but I don't know how to do it in detail. Please help me(Sorry for bad English).

Here is my code

```
$fn = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

while(!feof($fn)) {
    $result = fgets($fn);
    echo $result;
}

fclose($fn);
```

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`?

Comment: if your outputting then turn off output buffering.

Comment: Since you read line by line and don't store the lines anywhere, the code as you have posted it should use only as much memory as the longest line in your file. Where do you hit the memory limit?

Comment: @Joni When reading a line is finished, I store the data of that line into DB

Comment: @BenM I want to run this code without increase memory limit

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Can you show me how to do that in detail?

Comment: yes it should not get memory limit issue.  What exact error are you getting

Comment: Try giving a buffer length `fgets($fn, 65535);`

Comment: First off, turn off output.  Or simply don't output, and see if it works.  Probably the browser can't handle that much data all at one time.

Comment: "When reading a line is finished, I store the data of that line into DB" You should show us *that* code, then.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.generators.overview.php) to handle the memory usage. This is just an example written by a user on the documentation page:

```
function getLines($file)
{
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');

    try {
        while ($line = fgets($f)) {
            yield $line;
        }
    } finally {
        fclose($f);
    }
}

foreach (getLines("file.txt") as $n => $line) {
    // insert the line into db or do whatever you want with it.
}
```

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate. Instead, you can write a generator function, which is the same as a normal function, except that instead of returning once, a generator can yield as many times as it needs to in order to provide the values to be iterated over.

Comment: Awesome answer. Didn't realize that yield is a thing now in PHP. Since 5.5 even... curious how I've never seen it used until now. I really should read update notes...

Comment: @Tschallacka no worries, I also ain't seen it used until a few weeks ago. Once I saw it and read about it I was simply amazed. It could be used very often to overcome too much memory usage.

Comment: right now all the cases where I wrote difficult code to get around the memory limit and this thing was there all the time... I've been wishing php had a a yield method, but I never checked if it had... I could kick myself for not checking it out. I wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: I known about it for a while, but I don't see how it helps in this case as the only thing in memory is a single line, which is the case even with this generator.

Comment: Is it not necessary to trim the lines? Or how does it recognize when a line starts and a line ends? Do "fgets" trims the lines for you?

Answer (score 2):

PHP cleans memory best when a scope is cleared in my experience. A loop doesn't count as a scope, but a function does.
So handing your file pointer to a function, doing your database things within the function and then exiting the function for the loop, where you can call `gc_collect_cycles()` should help with managing your memory and to force php to clean up after itself.

I also recommend turning off echo, but rather log to a file. You can then use a command `tail -f filename` to read that log output(windows linux subsystem, git for windows bash, or on linux)

I use a similar method to below to handle large files with millions of entries, and it helps with staying under the memory limit.

```
function dostuff($fn) 
{
    $result = fgets($fn);
    // store database, do transforms, whatever
    echo $result;
}

$fn = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

while(!feof($fn)) {
    dostuff($fn);
    flush(); // only need this if you do the echo thing.
    gc_collect_cycles();
}

fclose($fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and [ob_get_level](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) to manage memory and output buffering.

> readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level().

You may still have PHP output buffering active while performing the read.

Check that with:

> You can use the following at the start of your script to stop output buffering if it's already started:

```
if (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_clean();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the memory limit like `ini_set('memory_limit',-1)`;//You script will not stoped until its finished the reading. but this is wrong way beacuse its take your CPU utilization time on server.

Better is to divide the file in chunks,

covert you file data to array then you can easily read it in chunks like

```
$file_lines = file('mytext.txt');
foreach ($file_lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

$file_lines is your array.